# Почему не добавляется class к элементу?

Tags: html, css, sass

Есть данный код:

```
    <ul class="cube-list" id="cube-list">
        <li class="blog"><a href="index.html">Blog</a></li>
        <li class="about"><a href="about.hmtl">About</a></li>
        <li class="login"><a href="login.html">Log in</a></li>
    </ul>
```

и стили для него(sass, компилирую в css), которые по идее должны добавляться через js:

```
.menu-for-mobile-opened
  position: absolute
  display: block
  width: 100%
  background-color: rgba(185, 174, 128, 1)
  text-align: center
  li 
      display: block
```

сам js:

```
var cubeList = document.getElementById("cube-list");

var cube = document.getElementById("cube");
cube.addEventListener("click", function(){
  //alert(this.style.display)
  cube.style.display = (cube.style.display == 'none') ? 'block' : 'none';
  //if (this.style.display == 'none')
      //cubeList.classList.remove('menu-for-mobile-opened');
  //else
      cubeList.classList.add("menu-for-mobile-opened");
});
```

в итоге класс добавляется, но элемент(список ul) никак не меняется. в чем проблема?

Comment: так а где элемент с ид cube?

Comment: @НазарКалитюк ну, я опустил эту часть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если cube это например кнопка для изменения стилей, то все работает

```js
var cubeList = document.getElementById("cube-list");

var cube = document.getElementById("cube");
cube.addEventListener("click", function(){
  cube.style.display = (cube.style.display == 'none') ? 'block' : 'none';
  cubeList.classList.add("menu-for-mobile-opened");
});
```

```css
.menu-for-mobile-opened {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(185, 174, 128, 1);
  text-align: center;
  }
 .menu-for-mobile-opened li {
      display: block
      }
```

```html
 <button id="cube">cube</button>
 <ul class="cube-list" id="cube-list">
        <li class="blog"><a href="index.html">Blog</a></li>
        <li class="about"><a href="about.hmtl">About</a></li>
        <li class="login"><a href="login.html">Log in</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

В общем, проблема в том, что если при создании страницы класс не использовался, то при компиляции sass он не будет добавлен в css файл.

Comment: наверно у вас еще плагин uncss кажеться.

Comment: @НазарКалитюк не, это вряд ли, я даже не знаю что это)